# Python - dump dictionary of lists into json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dump, serializable

Hi when I am running this code:

```
city_dict_humidity = dict()
city_dict_temperature = dict()

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
   if (msg.payload == 'Q'):
      client.disconnect()
topics = msg.topic.split('/')
if topics[2] == 'humidity':
    if topics[1] in city_dict_humidity:
        city_dict_humidity[topics[1]].append(msg.payload)
    else:
        city_dict_humidity[topics[1]] = [msg.payload]

elif topics[2] == 'temperature':
    if topics[1] in city_dict_temperature:
        city_dict_temperature[topics[1]].append(msg.payload) 
    else:
        city_dict_temperature[topics[1]] = [msg.payload]
vypis()
uloz_json()

def uloz_json():
   with open('data.json','w') as wrt:
      json.dump(city_dict_humidity,wrt)
```

I am getting an error: TyperError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable.
Where is the catch, please? Can't I have lists in there?

Comment: This means you are adding something with type bytes (b'like this') to the dict. It depends on where original `msg` variable comes from and what `vypis()` does. Best way to debug code is using interact: `import code` then inside `uloz_json` function add `code.interact(local=locals())`. Run code in the shell and it will stop inside `uloz_json` function. Write `city_dict_humidity` in the shell and check values for bytes type (with b in the beginning)

Comment: The problem lies in the data. You can have lists. If you read the error message, you'll find it's complaining about `bytes`. Bytes are unencoded sequences of characters. They're almost a string, but not quite. You need to make a choice about your bytes - either convert them to strings, or convert them to lists of integers.

Comment: to convert to plain string you'd do `msg.payload.decode()` or to get a list of ints (of each byte value) you'd do `list(msg.payload)`

Comment: Thank you, Tadhg McDonald-Jensen that is what I needed, didn't realize it's not sent as pure string/int...I was fixated too much on the list in dict thing